# is there any event that raise before updateComplete() for a Canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, event-handling, canvas

I have an app with a canvas which content changes dynamically.  In my app there is a progressbar which I want to show while the canvas update is executed. Is there any event to call just before the update starts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [creationComplete](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:creationComplete) or [dataChange](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/Container.html#event:dataChange)